# Static Control Scroll Bar not working Win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi, scrollbar

```
    case WM_VSCROLL: //in switch(message) in WinProc
            wmId = GetWindowLong((HWND) lParam, GWL_ID);
                        //only one scroll bar so don't check it
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
            case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                nScrollPos = HIWORD(wParam);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            SetScrollPos (hDirectives, SB_CTL, nScrollPos, TRUE);
            break;
    //where 
    hDirectives = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), NULL, 
WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | SS_RIGHT | SS_SUNKEN | WS_VSCROLL, 
                20, 20, 300, 300, hWnd, 
(HMENU) ID_DIRECTIVE, ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam) ->hInstance, NULL);
```

The window displays and I can put text in, but the scroll bar is not responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a window has the `WS_VSCROLL` / `WS_HSCROLL` styles, the scrollbar messages will be sent to **that** window, not its parent. In the above example you would need to sub-class the static control to process the scroll messages.

Comment: Hey Jonathan... facing the same problem and trying to get SCROLLINFO but not getting any value... tried to get all "ProcessModuleCollection modules = mainProcess.Modules" of that process to find any child have scroll info no luck
My question:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/76884383/5096993