# C# SCROLLINFO not working on Chrome window

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, scroll, user32

I am attempting to retrieve scroll information from the window handle, but I keep getting a value of 0. I am pursuing this approach because my goal is to capture a complete scrolling screenshot of the window. The intention is to enable automatic scrolling and image capture. While I have successfully implemented automatic window scrolling, I've encountered variations in the scrolling behaviour for different windows.

For instance, sending a mouse delta of 100 results in Chrome scrolling by around 70 pixels, whereas Visual Studio scrolls by approximately 110 pixels. Each window appears to exhibit distinct scrolling characteristics. Therefore, my current objective is to calculate the precise amount of pixel movement during scrolling using the scrollbar. However, I have encountered difficulties in achieving this functionality.

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCROLLINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos;
}
public enum ScrollInfoMask : uint
{
    SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
    SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
    SIF_POS = 0x4,
    SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
    SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
    SIF_ALL = (SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS),
}

public enum SBOrientation : int
{
    SB_HORZ = 0x0,
    SB_VERT = 0x1,
    SB_CTL = 0x2,
    SB_BOTH = 0x3
}

// get scrollbar info
SCROLLINFO scrollinfo = new SCROLLINFO();
scrollinfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCROLLINFO));
scrollinfo.fMask = (uint)ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL; // or SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS, etc.

bool success = GetScrollInfo(hWnd, (int)SBOrientation.SB_VERT, ref scrollinfo);
        if (success)
        {
            // Process scrollinfo here
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle error here
        }

uint errorCode = GetLastError();
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve scroll info. Error code: {errorCode}");

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hWnd, int fnBar, ref SCROLLINFO lpsi);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetLastError();
```

Getting "False" from GetScrollInfo
and GetLastError() returns 1447 error code

**It's working on Notepad Window... but not working on Chrome, Firefox, visual studio etc**

"I'm essentially looking to capture scrolling screenshots. I have two options:

Automatically scroll through the content using code and calculate the distance scrolled in pixels. Then, I'll capture that specific portion and append it to the image.
Alternatively, I can scroll a predefined height. This way, if I scroll 100 pixels, for instance, I'll capture an image of exactly 100 pixels.
I'm currently attempting option 1, but I haven't been successful so far."

Comment: According to your description, I wonder if you mean `GetScrollInfo` always return 0? If so, I suggest you could try to call `GetLastError` to get extended error information.

"Each window appears to exhibit distinct scrolling characteristics. " As far as I'm concerned, it depends on the page size. You could refer to the Doc:[Scroll Box Position and Scrolling Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-scroll-bars#scroll-box-position-and-scrolling-range)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT getting error code of 1447.. update question also added GetLastError 
Basically, I want to scroll screenshots.. so I have 2 options 
1) After scrolling automatically by code calculate how much pixel scroll moved and I will capture that part and attach it to the image
2) If I am able to scroll pre-define height so, in that case, I know I scrolled 100 pixels so capture a 100-pixel image only
trying option 1 but no luck yet..

Comment: Apps like Chrome and Visual Studio do not have standard UIs these days, and I suspect GetScrollInfo simply won't work because they provide their own scrollbar rather than using the OS implementation.

Comment: @JonathanPotter any idea how we can get details of their scroll bar... i am able to scroll Chrome scroll bar automatically but unable to get details.. like how much the scroll bar scrolled... Basically, I want to capture full scroll screenshots of that window

Comment: ERROR_NO_SCROLLBARS:The window does not have scroll bars. 

Applications use the `GetScrollInfo` function. A window receives `SBM_GETSCROLLINFO message` through its `WindowProc` function. Applications which implement a custom scroll bar control must respond to these messages for the GetScrollInfo function to work properly.

The scrollbars in Chrome are not native scrollbars, so they do not respond to the messages or the regular windowing API.

As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't use `GetScrollInfo` for Chrome and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize the `SCROLLINFO` structure properly before using it.

```
SCROLLINFO scrollinfo = new SCROLLINFO();
scrollinfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCROLLINFO));
scrollinfo.fMask = SIF_ALL; // or SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS, etc.
```

And handle `return` value of `GetScrollInfo`: The `GetScrollInfo` function returns a boolean indicating success or failure. Make sure you're checking this return value to ensure that the scroll information is indeed being retrieved.

```
bool success = GetScrollInfo(windowHandle, SB_HORZ, ref scrollinfo);
if (success)
{
    // Process scrollinfo here
}
else
{
    // Handle error here
}
```

Use the Right Scroll Bar Constant: The `fnBar` parameter in the `GetScrollInfo` function indicates whether you're querying the horizontal or vertical scrollbar. Make sure you're using the correct constant values: `SB_HORZ` for horizontal and `SB_VERT` for vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Hey tried this still not working getting a "FALSE" return... Update Question code also check once

Answer (score 0):

### There are no scrollbars...

These days you rarely see modern applications with `native` scrollbars. `Visual Studio` has one single top-level native window handle (a `HWND`). The top-level window could theoretically have a scrollbar, but usually will not.

### ...just pixels!

Now, when you see those scrollbars in, what appears to be child windows, in e.g. `Visual Studio` and `Chrome`, chances are that those are just *rendered* pixels. I.e. There is no native scrollbar to look for.

Since we know that `Visual Studio` is a [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/?view=netdesktop-7.0) application, we can get hold of scrollbar information using some `WPF` related tricks. Obviously, such tricks will not work for non-WPF applications (like `Chrome`). For `Chrome` there might be some way to read the [DOM](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/properties/) outside the browser, but expect it to be non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem lies in the fact that applications like Chrome, Firefox, and Visual Studio don't necessarily use the standard Windows scrollbar mechanism. Therefore, using the GetScrollInfo API won't work with these applications as intended. As a result, "fixing" the code in the traditional sense may not yield the desired outcome.

However, I can provide a solution based on the first recommendation: differentiating by the Window Class. The following code will attempt to use GetScrollInfo for applications that support it (like Notepad), but for known classes (like Chrome's) it will use predefined values.

```
Here's an updated approach:
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

public void HandleScrolling(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(256);
    GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity);

    if (className.ToString() == "Chrome_WidgetWin_1") // This is the class name for Chrome's main window as of my last update. You might need to verify.
    {
        // Handle Chrome's scrolling. You might need to tweak this.
        int pixelsScrolled = 70;
        CaptureImage(pixelsScrolled);
    }
    else
    {
        SCROLLINFO scrollinfo = new SCROLLINFO();
        scrollinfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCROLLINFO));
        scrollinfo.fMask = (uint)ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;

        bool success = GetScrollInfo(hWnd, (int)SBOrientation.SB_VERT, ref scrollinfo);
        if (success)
        {
            int pixelsScrolled = scrollinfo.nPos; // This is a simplistic approach. You might need to calculate the difference from the previous nPos value.
            CaptureImage(pixelsScrolled);
        }
        else
        {
            uint errorCode = GetLastError();
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve scroll info for window class {className}. Error code: {errorCode}");
        }
    }
}

public void CaptureImage(int pixelsScrolled)
{
    // Your logic to capture an image of the specified height.
}
```

In this approach, we first check the class name of the window. If it's a known class like Chrome, we use predefined scrolling values. For other windows, we attempt to use the GetScrollInfo API.

Remember, this method is still somewhat fragile because it relies on known window class names and predefined scrolling values. You'll need to maintain and update this list as needed.