# C# Scroll window(Chomre, FireFox) perticular pixel using Window handle

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, scroll

Like previously I tried to get ScrollInfo of the window but it's not working on Chrome or other windows where they are using a custom scroll bar....

So it's possible to scroll windows by code particular height like I want to scroll Chomre window 100 Pixel?

i tried to scroll windows by mouse delta also but it's different for each window.. so looking for a fixed like want to scroll 100 pixels for any type of window(Chrome, Visual Studio etc)

Code I tried

```
InputHelpers.SendVerticalMouseWheel(-100);

internal class InputHelpers
{
    internal static bool SendKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode keyCode)
    {
        var manager = new InputManager();
        manager.SendKeyPress(keyCode);
        return manager.SendInputs();
    }

    internal static bool SendVerticalMouseWheel(int delta)
    {
        InputManager inputManager = new InputManager();
        inputManager.AddVerticalMouseWheel(delta);
        return inputManager.SendInputs();
    }

    internal static bool SendHorizontalMouseWheel(int delta)
    {
        InputManager inputManager = new InputManager();
        inputManager.AddHorizontalMouseWheel(delta);
        return inputManager.SendInputs();
    }
}

public class InputManager
{
    public List<INPUT> InputList { get; private set; }

    public InputManager()
    {
        InputList = new List<INPUT>();
    }

    internal void SendKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode key)
    {
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        input.Type = InputType.InputKeyboard;
        input.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        input.Data.Keyboard.wVk = key;
        input.Data.Keyboard.dwFlags = KeyboardEventFlags.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        InputList.Add(input);

        input = new INPUT();
        input.Type = InputType.InputKeyboard;
        input.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        input.Data.Keyboard.wVk = key;
        InputList.Add(input);
    }

    internal void AddVerticalMouseWheel(int delta)
    {
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        input.Type = InputType.InputMouse;
        input.Data.Mouse = new MOUSEINPUT();
        input.Data.Mouse.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL;
        input.Data.Mouse.mouseData = (uint)delta;
        InputList.Add(input);
    }

    internal void AddHorizontalMouseWheel(int delta)
    {
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        input.Type = InputType.InputMouse;
        input.Data.Mouse = new MOUSEINPUT();
        input.Data.Mouse.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL;
        input.Data.Mouse.mouseData = (uint)delta;
        InputList.Add(input);
    }

    public bool SendInputs()
    {
        INPUT[] inputList = InputList.ToArray();
        uint len = (uint)inputList.Length;
        uint successfulInputs = NativeMethods.SendInput(len, inputList, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
        return successfulInputs == len;
    }
}

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]         
 public static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] 
INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
```

Comment: Each scroll value (if the window his scrollable itself) will be per application. There is extremely rarely a need to control that. This sound like you have a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Franck i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/q/76884383/5096993 but it's not working on Chrome or other windows where they are using a custom scroll bar.... so now i trying so scroll window particular height so tried delta but it's not working..

Comment: wont work on visual studio. It's WPF and it's just a DirectX rendering. You need specific WPF code if you want to control it or VSIX tool

Comment: @Franck Yes so i am trying to do that on Visual Studio, chrome etc..Basically, I want to scroll screenshots.. so I have 2 options 1) After scrolling automatically by code calculate how much pixel scroll moved and I will capture that part and attach it to the image 2) If I am able to scroll pre-define height so, in that case, I know I scrolled 100 pixels so capture a 100-pixel image only trying option 1 but no luck yet.

Comment: "scroll 100 pixels for any type of window"
I suggest you could try to use [scrollBy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741495(v=vs.85)) or [scrollTo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741497(v=vs.85))